# Using string in function in child class gets null in Java

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance, nullpointerexception

I've been learning Java recently, and it's quite different than most other languages. 
I and a few others have stood around scratching our heads not able to see why something doesn't work, and this is a problem that I see ALL. THE. TIME. 
It's frustrating and irritating, hopefully I can shed some light on this for some other people.

Ever ask yourself this ?:

"I've been trying to get this to work for hours and I just can't seem to see it. 
I'm trying to pass the string "reducerFractions" to the FractionReducer class, but somehow, when it gets into that class it becomes null?

I'm really new with Java and this is only my second program with it, I can't quite get why this isn't working...

### ParentClass:

```
public class FractionCalc extends FractionUI
{
//member variables for this class initialized here, all are kept within this class
protected String reducerFractions;
{
/*Paramiters in here math stuff ect*/
finalNum = (int)fin_num;
finalDem = (int)fin_dem;
reducerFractions = finalNum + "/" + finalDem; 
//puts these together in a protected string

System.out.println(reducerFractions); //<- testing here shows its working as needed
reducer.setFraction(finalNum, finalDem);
//overloading the function shows it's working for the two ints as ints themselves
reducer.setFraction(reducerFractions);
int rNum = reducer.getResultsNum();
int rDenom = reducer.getResultsDenom();
String debug = rNum + " " + rDenom;
System.out.println(debug); 
//right here gives back the correct numbers using an int approach
}
```

### Child Class:

```
public class FractionReducer extends FractionCalc
{
  public void setFraction(String a)
{
    System.out.println(reducerFractions);
    //Right here it's saying it's null, I don't understand why...
    String[] stringReducedFraction = reducerFractions.split("/");
    double numerator = Float.valueOf(stringReducedFraction[0]);
    double denominator = Float.valueOf(stringReducedFraction[1]);
    //split up the string here for other uses
 }
//Other stuff
}
```

## Terminal Output

```
2/1 //The string prints out fine in the parent class
null//but null in the child?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FractionReducer.setFraction(FractionReducer.java:25)
    at FractionCalc.FractionCalc(FractionCalc.java:73)
    at FractionUI.Run(FractionUI.java:47)
    at MainP2.main(MainP2.java:19)
```

There's an obvious (to most) problem here, but it's only obvious once you've worked with objects a lot.

Comment: Can't figure out without some of the omitted codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you pass reducerFractions into FractionReducer as the String argument a. So if you replace your references to reducerFractions with references to a it should work for you. Like this:

```
     public void setFraction(String a)
{
    System.out.println(a);
    //Right here it's saying it's null, I don't understand why...
    String[] stringReducedFraction = a.split("/");
    double numerator = Float.valueOf(stringReducedFraction[0]);
    double denominator = Float.valueOf(stringReducedFraction[1]);
    //split up the string here for other uses
 }
```

Making the String protected and static is not the way to go really. If you need it in FractionReducer, you should pass it in.

Comment: Hey that's really great, I didn't even think of that. 

Great catch. I was helping my friend out with this code and it took us like 20 minutes to figure out making it static worked,but yours is MUCH better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, gee there. 
The problem is obviously something with sharing permissions.

Correct!

Most people would think you just need to swap the string over to public, welll we don't want to do that, we need to protect our data, guard it closely to prevent bugs, erroneous errors, and misinformation.

What needs to be realized here is that, you need to see it from the child class. Sure the child class can see it, because it's protected, but it's also dynamic. 
So it's essentially changing.

That's right, so all we need to do is change it to static so that the information can flow, and since it's protected, it wont be interfered with.

I hope this helped some of you, or at least someone.

```
protected static String reducerFractions;
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer to the question as a static variable is something completely different than an instance variable. Your program will not work as expected with static variables and several threads. Please extend your question to show you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You try to access you field `reducerFractions` from a method that is called from a initializer. I think that the field is not fully initialized when you call the method.

Can you please post code that meets the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) criteria?